# Combobox in Excel relative to other combobox

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi have a table similar to this one

```
+--------+------+
| Family | Type |
+--------+------+
|        | dog  |
+ Canine +------+
|        | fox  |
+--------+------+
|        | Lion |
+        +------+
| Feline | cat  |
+        +------+
|        | Lynx |
+--------+------+
```

and I have another table where I want the user to select with a combobox the `Family` and the `Type` with comboboxes.

I can create the first combobox, but how to display in the second one only the `Type` related to the `Family`?

(Lets' assume that my animals table starts from a1)

Answer (score 1):

I will show you how, using a slightly different example. You should be able to modify the solution to fit your needs.

First I start with 3 lists.  The first list are simply the inputs for the first combobox, the other two are sublists depending what has been chosen:

[image]

In order to make the first drop down (as you figured out), select it, goto data -> Data Validation.

Under Allow, select List, chose your source:

[image]

Up to this point you should be fine. In order to make the sublist, do it similarly but put a conditional statement in the souce field this time:

[image]

I used a very simple condition that will only look for "b" but of course you could expand upon this idea.

Overall the soltion for you is to add conditions to the data validation selection.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Say now I want to add Reptiles or whatever? I suppose there is not a SWITCH statement...

Comment: Well then simply add another category to the initial list. What I have posted still applies.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html)

Using the `INDIRECT` function and a bit of workaround you can actually extend the lists without touching the formulas.